# Syntax Error when importing Flask with Apache

Tags: python, apache, virtualenv

Having trouble getting my Flask/Apache application to work. I seem to be able to import my application fine in my api.wsgi file. But when my api.py (flask) app is actually being read I encounter the following error:

[image]

It LOOKS like an error you'd get when the wrong version of Python is being run. But you can see by the directory it's using python 3.7. So the annotation syntax should be fine.

I however did notice this line a few lines up from it:
[image]

Does this mean it's actually using Python 2.7? If so wouldn't that be causing the issue?
This is my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:1024>
     WSGIDaemonProcess flask_api python-path=/var/www/html/flask_api:/var/www/html/flask_api/flask_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages
     # Add machine's IP address (use ifconfig command)
     ServerName 3.23.72.183
     # DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/flask_api/
     # Give an alias to to start your website url with
     WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/html/flask_api/api.wsgi
     <Directory /var/www/html/flask_api>
            WSGIProcessGroup flask_api
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                # set permissions as per apache2.conf file
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
     </Directory>
     LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using a venv. How do I make sure Apache is using python 3.7? globally I have both python 2.7 and 3 installed.

Comment: The mod_wsgi module needs to be compiled against Python 3.7 (or whichever version you like). The virtualenv doesn't matter.

Comment: "*…you can see by the directory it's using python 3.7…*" No, I see it's Python 2.7 running code from Python 3.7 `site-packages`.

Comment: @AKX okay, but how do I go about this?

Comment: You'd honestly probably have a better time running `gunicorn` or another WSGI server, then using `mod_proxy`'s reverse proxying to have Apache forward requests there, than to use `mod_wsgi`.